# Summernote html code view when htmlMode true is not working fine with codemirror

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror, summernote

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        codemirror: {
            theme: 'monokai',
            htmlMode: true
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<textarea class="summernote"><p><br></p>
<p>Testing html </p>
<p><br> formatting<br></p></textarea>
```

When you click code view, it doesn't format html properly, it does xml instead. As you can see, `<br>` tags are interpreted as invalid xml tag, however `htmlMode: true` is set and is supposed to be used to interpret the content as html.

Comment: Please include the code you're having a problem with *in the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I need to set:

```
codemirror: {
      ...
      htmlMode: true,
      lineNumbers: true,
      mode: 'text/html'
    }
```

Despite these are supposed to be default values.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ungue/fzt257r6/41/